# How to trigger the region monitoring in all views

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cllocationmanager

I am trying to use region monitoring in my swift application in a way to get a local notifications when I am in range and out of range. The application has 3 different ViewControllers were I can navigate from one viewController to another and back. I have the following code in my initial viewcontroller and I get the local notification when I am in range and out of range. Also as long as application is minimized regardless of each of the 3 viewcontroller I am, I get the local notification. But if the application is running on the foreground, I only get the local notification if I am on the first viewcontroller where I have this code. One way is to put the same code in all viewcontrollers but not sure if this is a good idea or design. What else can I do in order to get local notification regardless of which view I am while application is running in foreground?

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    print("Entering region")
    print(region.identifier)
    myTitle = "Entering the range"
    var alertView = UIAlertController(title: myTitle, message: "Press OK to continue", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: yesHandler))
    presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    alertBody1 = "Entering the range"
    LocalNotification()    
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    print("Exiting region")
    myTitle = "Entering the range"
    var alertView = UIAlertController(title: myTitle, message: "Press OK to continue", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: yesHandler))
    presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    alertBody1 = "Exiting the range"
    LocalNotification()
}
```

Comment: I would normally set up location monitoring in the AppDelegate or another object that is held by the AppDelegate and then have that object issue `NSNotifications` when regions are entered/exited.  The various view controllers can subscribe to those notifications

Comment: Is there a sample code that I can reference as how to let view controllers subscribe to it?

Comment: Start with the class reference for NSNotification. Also look at this http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/

Comment: So I moved all the code related to region monitoring to the AppDelegate.swift file. It seems  that it works, but this line gives me error if is not un-commented   presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil).-------- The error is unresolved identifier presentViewController .

Comment: Yeah, you can't just present a random view controller from within the app delegate.  Post a notification and let the existing view controller deal with it

Comment: one other question. When the related code to the region monitoring was in the first view controller, I was still getting local notification when application was terminated. But now since the code is moved to AppDelegate, I no longer get local notification when in range and out of range if application is terminated. Anything I can do to solve this issue?

Comment: How are you instantiating your CLLocationManager?  In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?  Have you specified background location mode and `always` permission?

Comment: func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        print("applicationDidBecomeActive")
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103450/discussion-between-paulw11-and-borna).

Comment: Paulw, As you mentioned I placed the initialization inside  
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool { 
as you suggested and is now working all the way. Thanks so much for your great help on this